# Tire sidewall advice

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

Haven't had the best luck with tires so I'm pretty cautious (aka paranoid) about something happening to them. Took a turn an it too close today and rubbed my rear right tire along it at around 35 mph.. not a true gash but there is signs of running. Anything to be worried about? Should I apply rubber glue to the area? Possible risk of popping? Tires are Michelin premier a/s 205/50r17 93h XL BSW(whatever that means)

[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Not an answer to your _actual_ question, but those numbers (205/40/17 93h) are width in mm, height between rim + tyre as a percent of the total width, alloy size in inches, load index, where the number 93 refers to the max weight per tyre (in this case 650kg) and the letter is the max speed allowed while carrying the max load. The "BSW" is just the _style_ of the tyre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of hard to see in the photo's,  but if you could lift the tear and see the braids/strings(sorry can't remember proper term to save my life) then it's time to replace the tire. If it's just scratched/skinned the tire you should be ok

Comment: Agreed. This looks like it's just a rub on the sidewall. Happens all the time. Keep it on the rear for now. If it doesn't leak air and no performance issues (wobbling), there should be no issues going forward.

Comment: @cano plies or ply...

Comment: Thank you all, there is a small piece of rubber that I can lift up but it does not seem to be too deep. Would there be any help if I applied a rubber glue to the area? Again, I really appreciate the replies, very helpful

Comment: @solar Mike, that's it!! Thank you and @ Katie  go ahead, it won't hurt anything.

Comment: Take more pictures while holding the rubber lacerated portion on the tire. Fill the tires to the recommended PSI level. Monitor it closely for a few hours. If air is leaking more than 2 PSI in 1 hour. Change them according to the thread life and Drive terrain (on your unspecified/unlisted vehicle)